# How can I find an agency for copywriting/script writing (for advertising) in the UK?

Tags: creative-writing, script, copywriting

I'm a creative copywriter and I've done the odd voice-over writing gig. Think ads and brand videos. I enjoy them a lot, and thought I'd seek out some agencies that specialise in creative copy for video and ads, but I'm struggling to find them.  How can I go about searching for agencies who can help me?

Comment: Hi bels and welcome to Writers.  I've edited your question to make it fit better with Stack Exchange norms.  Questions asking for lists or recommendations don't work well; they're pretty subjective and it's hard to evaluate the answers. But your core problem seems to be "how do I find them?", so I've changed your question to ask that.  (It's possible that, if there are clear frontrunners in this area, some specific suggestions will come up in answers.)  Thanks for understanding, and please feel free to [edit] further if I've misunderstood you.

Answer (score 1):

I'd just approach it like any job:

- Tell everyone you know you're looking for some work and specifically what you're looking for, and if they know anyone they could introduce you to or if they have any gigs
- Cold calls/emails to agencies (both ones you'd like to work for and one you wouldn't, having a strong CV only helps over time). Google them, then call and speak to someone about possible positions, then follow up via email with your CV
- Go to events held by agencies and hit them with business cards and make connections and ask around for what you're looking for